# Mergesort to sort doubles in java. Problems with comparable

Tags: java, double, mergesort

```
public class MergeSort {

    private void sort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
        if (lo > hi) return;
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        sort(a, aux, lo, mid - 1);
        merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    public void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[a.length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.length);
    }

    public void merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux,
                             int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= hi; i ++) {
            aux[i] = a[i];
        }

        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < hi; k ++) {
            if (i > mid) aux[k] = a[j++];
            else if (j > hi) aux[k] = a[i++];
            else if (less(a[i], a[j])) aux[k] = a[i++];
            else aux[k] = a[j++];
        }
    }

    private boolean less(Comparable a, Comparable b) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) == -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the above code for mergesort algorithm. Now I want to use it to sort an array of doubles. However, it throws an error by saying: sort(java.lang.Comparable[]) can not be applied to  (double[]). My question is why is this happening and how to avoid it? In my understanding, if double implements Comparable (which it true) the code must work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class **D**ouble implements comparable, but you seem to pass an array of the [primitive datatype](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-premitive-data-type.php) **d**ouble. Primitives are not Objects at all and therefore incompatible with `Comparable`. If it weren't an array but just a single value, you wouldn't notice because of automatic [boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: I initiated double[] tmp = new double[10]; then populated it with random doubles. Now while trying to sort the 'tmp' I saw the error. What is wrong with passing an array of the primitives?

Comment: Well, and my own comment: primitives are not objects at all and therefore incompatible with the interface `Comparable`. The supplied link may highlight this, I hope.

Comment: The links are not working for me. Also, I have supplied the exact error: "sort(java.lang.Comparable[]) can not be applied to (double[])"

Comment: yes, I saw that eventually. If you google *primitive type for java* you may find some more in depth explanation. Actually it would be enough to define an `Double[] d = {1d,2d,3d};` to resolve your issue, but you'd miss out on the implicit boxing happening in this, as opposed to `Double[] d = {Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(2), Double.valueOf(3),};`

Comment: In that case, can you help me to understand how can I apply MergeSort to int[], double[], etc.?

Comment: Generically you mean, similar like in your code? You can't have that with primitive types. You don't want to use the object types, Integer, Double...?